# Need insight on how to fix my programming assignment in C++

Tags: c++

I'm not asking for someone to literally do my assignment, I actually have almost everything done. 
1. My ansiicodes do not work the way I want it to, as well as my while loop that may be incorrect too but I'm hoping someone can explain to me why it would not be working. My assignment requires that with values less than 15%, the font must be bold and red, blahblabhalbah, and values greater than 100% the font must also be bold and red. But my first and last values are not being colored. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "ansiicodes.h"
using namespace std;

const int ONE_HUNDRED = 100;
const int EMPTY_CELL = 3000;
const int CELL_RANGE = 1200;

int main() {

    //User inputting minimum and maximum voltages
    int minVoltage = 0;
    int maxVoltage = 0;
    int voltStepSize = 0;

    cout << "Battery Voltage to Sate of Charge (SoC) Generator" << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Enter minimum voltages to show in table [mV]: " 
         << ANSII_BOLD << ANSII_UNDERLINE;
    cin >> minVoltage;
    cout << ANSII_NORMAL
         << "Enter maximum voltages to show in table [mV]: "
         << ANSII_BOLD << ANSII_UNDERLINE;
    cin >> maxVoltage;
    cout << ANSII_NORMAL 
         << "Enter voltage step size [mV]: "
         << ANSII_BOLD << ANSII_UNDERLINE;
    cin >> voltStepSize;
    cout << ANSII_NORMAL << endl;

    //Display of Voltage, SoC, Description Titles
    cout << ANSII_BOLD;    
    cout << setw(10) << "Voltage";
    cout << setw(6) << "SoC";
    cout << setw(13) << "Description" << endl;
    cout << setw(10) << "-------";
    cout << setw(5) << " ------";
    cout << setw(11) << "----------" << endl;
    cout << ANSII_NORMAL;

    //Displaying of Percentages
    int voltage = minVoltage;  

    while (voltage<=maxVoltage){
        cout << setw(8) << voltage << "mV ";
        int stateOfCharge = (voltage-EMPTY_CELL) * ONE_HUNDRED/CELL_RANGE;
        voltage += voltStepSize;

        //Less than 15%            
        if (stateOfCharge>=0 && stateOfCharge<=15){
            cout << ANSII_BOLD << ANSII_RED << setw(5) << stateOfCharge << "%"; 
            cout << setw(9) << "Too Low!" << endl;
        }           

        //Greater than or equal 15% but less than 35%            
        else if (stateOfCharge>=15 && stateOfCharge<35){
            cout << ANSII_CYAN << setw(5) << stateOfCharge << "%";
            cout << setw(5) << "Low!" << ANSII_NORMAL << endl;
        }

        //Greater than or equal 35% but les than 95%            
        else if (stateOfCharge>=35 && stateOfCharge<95){    
            cout << setw(5) << stateOfCharge << "%";
            cout << setw(3) << "OK" << ANSII_NORMAL << endl ;
        }

        //Greater than or equal 95 but less or equal 100%            
        else if (stateOfCharge>=95 && stateOfCharge<=100){
            cout << ANSII_GREEN << setw(5) << stateOfCharge << "%";
            cout << setw(5) << "Full" << ANSII_NORMAL << endl;
        }  

        //Greater than 100%            
        else if (stateOfCharge>100){
            cout << ANSII_BOLD << ANSII_RED << setw(5) << ONE_HUNDRED << "%";
            cout << " CAUTION: OverCharged!" << endl;
        }      
    }   
}
```

Comment: I advise you trying to create a shorter program having the same issue first. Shorter questions get more attention and trying to narrow down the question often helps finding the answer yourself.
And also: keep your excused, come to the point immediately.

Comment: What are those `ANSII_` variables declared + defined as?

Comment: What the heck is "ansii"?

Comment: @melpomene A love child of ANSI and ASCII?

Comment: @n.m. euthanize it now.  You know it's the right thing to do.

Comment: Try adding 'else cout << endl; cout << ANSII_NORMAL;` in the end of your big if sequence. Then think why you output a low charge warning for voltages from about 3000 to 3200 mv, but no warning for voltages below about 3000.